# Movie with a large mountain that hid a train depot

Tags: story-identification, movie

I saw a movie on TV in 1992 or 1993 that prominently featured a train depot that was hidden inside of a mountain. I believe the depot was the main hideout of the 'good guys' in the film.

The depot was marked by an 'end of line' maker on the tracks consisting of a wooden board with some 'caution' markings on it. When the characters wanted to enter, they would drive the train up to this marker, somehow communicate with staff inside, at which point the false front of the mountain would slide to the side. The marker was attached to the facade, so it would side along with the rest of the mountain so that the train could enter.

I'm not sure of the time period, but they were definitely using steam engines.

There may have been supernatural or fantasy-tech elements, but I can't remember much beyond the hidden train depot.

Comment: I'm not seeing anything scifi or fantastical here other than "*There may have been supernatural elements*". Can you offer any reason why this should be on-topic here?

Comment: Was this a cartoon? Live action? In English? Dubbed? Subbed?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Live action.

Comment: @Valorum vote to close if you want.

Comment: @Skoddie - I just have, but I was rather hoping that you could enlighten us

Comment: @Valorum the scope of Science Fiction and Fantasy is not actually defined in the help center. I'd consider a Western to be a subgenre of Fantasy, though as I said I'm fairly certain that there were supernatural (or perhaps tech-fantasy) elements in the film. Story identification is on topic for this SE, Movies has decided its not. If you can suggest a more appropriate SE I'm all ears.

Comment: @Skoddie: Story-identification is indeed on topic if there's a reasonable good-faith belief in science fiction and fantasy elements. I'm up in the air as to whether this would be the case. FWIW, I've done a few searches, but I haven't found anything yet.

Comment: @Skoddie - Westerns are not Fantasy by any reasonable definition of the word.

Comment: @Valorum then what exactly are they? And what is your reasonable definition of Fantasy?

Comment: @Skoddie - All fiction is a form of fantasy but that doesn't mean it's big F Fantasy

Comment: @Skoddie, The Adventures of Brisco County, Jr.; Legend (1995); The Ghosts of Watt O'Hugh; The Lost Regiment Series (civil war, horses, aliens, wormholes); The Wild, Wild, West. I wouldn't make such a broad statement about science fiction and westerns.